# Походження слова "вельон"

Tags: етимологія

Нещодавно я почув як "[фату](http://sum.in.ua/s/fata)" називають "вельоном". Та й є пісня "[Горіла сосна палала](https://nashe.com.ua/song/5647)", де є такі слова:

> Під білий вельон, під хустку, 
>   Більш не підете за дружку.

Однак, цікавить походження цього слова, так як в [ЕСУМі](http://history.org.ua/LiberUA/EtSlUkrM_1982/EtSlUkrM_1982.pdf) його чомусь немає.

Comment: Московсько український словник 1918 року перекладає фату як намітка венчальна.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[З Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0):

> Вельо́н (від пол. [welon](https://wsjp.pl/do_druku.php?id_hasla=58412&id_znaczenia=0) — «вуаль», «серпанок»; від італ. velo) —
>   легке, звичайно довге, покривало з тюлю, серпанку, шовку або мережива
>   як весільний головний убір нареченої.

Comment: Будь ласка, вказуйте джерела інформації.

Comment: Дякую за відповідь, але от що дивно - Вікіпедія дає аж три посилання на підтвердження цих слів, але в жодному з них (хоч, можливо, я не побачив) немає нічого про походження цього слова, а лише його визначення.